# Can continuations be used as a replacement for recursion?

Tags: ruby, recursion, continuations

The following function generates a 'stack level too deep (SystemStackError)' for n = 5,000

```
def factorial(n)
  n == 0 ? 1 : factorial(n -1) * n
end
```

Is there a way to avoid this error using continuations/callcc?

**Note:**

I know this can be implemented without recursion. e.g.

```
def factorial2(n)
  (1..n).inject(1) {|result, n| result * n } 
end
```

Comment: You don't need the parameter to inject, it defaults to the first element of the Enumerable it is called on. Also with a Ruby supporting Symbol#to_proc (1.8.7+, 1.8.6 + Facets) you can write factorial2 like this:

(1..n).inject(&:*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Continuations can do anything! However, you'll end up reinventing one of two things: a loop or a function call. On my machine, which does tail-call optimization by default, tail recursion with call/cc does *not* get optimized. The program quickly bogs down as each `callcc` apparently captures the entire call stack. That code being broken, here is a call/cc loop:

```
def fact( n )
    (n, f, k) = callcc { |k| [ n, 1, k ] }
    if ( n == 0 ) then return f
    else k.call n-1, n*f, k
    end
end
```

**Note:** previously I'd forgotten that call/cc isn't just about initiating a continuation-passing chain and got confused about the need for recursion, hence the comments below.

Comment: Or better yet, just don't use recursion to solve factorial. That doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @Billy: Indeed. But it's a good model problem when trying out any new control-flow construct.

Comment: I'm finding inject is faster for n = 10,000 but continuations faster for n = 100,000.

Comment: @Sam: How curious! I see a **2x** speedup using either of these implementations vs `f = 1; 100000.times { |i| i != 0 && ( f *= i ) }` or a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable tail-call optimization with `tailcall_optimize :factorial`, taken from [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7431).

```
class Class
  def tailcall_optimize( *methods )
    methods.each do |meth|
      org = instance_method( meth )
      define_method( meth ) do |*args|
        if Thread.current[ meth ]
          throw( :recurse, args )
        else
          Thread.current[ meth ] = org.bind( self )
          result = catch( :done ) do
            loop do
              args = catch( :recurse ) do
                throw( :done, Thread.current[ meth ].call( *args ) )
              end
            end
          end
          Thread.current[ meth ] = nil
          result
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

See [this interesting post](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1256) about determining if tail recursion is enabled.

Comment: Every time I think I've "seen the Elephant," a snippet of Ruby comes along that makes me feel as green as the newest recruit.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me.  Please post a complete solution.

Comment: I can't seem to get this formatted nicely, so here it is in uglytext.


    class Fact

      def fact(n, acc)
        if n==1
          acc
        else
          fact(n-1, n*acc)
        end
      end

      tailcall_optimize :fact

      def factorial(n)
        fact(n,1)
      end
    end

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the function returns `factorial(n -1) * n` which is a expression and no single recursive call. If you manage to have only the function call in the return statement, then the function is called **tail recursive**, and a good compiler / interpreter (i am not sure if Ruby is capable of it) can do some optimizations to avoid the usage of the stack.

Such a tail-recursive function might look like this, but please note that I'm not a Ruby programmer, so I am neither used to the syntax nor to the features of the interpreter. But you might be able to try it on your own:

```
def factorial(n, result=1)
    n == 0 ? result : factorial(n-1, result * n)
end
```

Comment: Ok, Ruby doesn't (always) do tail call optimization. So, on some ruby implementations this code might work and on others not... See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824562/does-ruby-perform-tail-call-optimization

Comment: This depends on the compiler/intepreter. Ruby does not guarantee tail-call optimization, as MRI Ruby itself is not tail-recursive. An implementation like MacRuby should be able to do it.

Comment: Although my understanding of continuations is weak, can you please explain how tail recursive calls relate to continuations as I didn't think they were that related?

Comment: This implementation works for n < 4415 where as the one i provide above only works upto 2865

Comment: @KalebPederson The tail call _is_ the continuation of a tail-recursive function since the caller effectively hands control over to the callee.