# Fastest way to get Percent of rows with incorrect values for each feature in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, data-wrangling

Below code is what I have.  Seems to work for `?, '`  and `''` but not for `np.NaN`. Any suggestions?

Also, I am new to Pandas/Python and hence would like to know if there is a faster way to do this

I am thinking of treating features as suspect if more than X%(say 5%) of the rows have missing values.  Any other data sanitization initial checks that you regularly use

```
for col in df.columns:
  pcnt_missing = df[df[col].isin(['?','',' ',np.NaN])][col].count() * 100.0 / df[col].count()
  if pcnt_missing > 1:
    print(f"Col = {col}, Percent missing ={pcnt_missing:.2f}")
```

Comment: I think you should check [pd.DataFrame.dropna method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html). Furthermore, you should try to avoid `for` loops while using `pandas`, because [python is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305518/why-is-equivalent-python-code-so-much-slower) and when you use `pandas` methods, they usually run on C.

Comment: @FelipeWhitaker ```dropna``` has several issues that don't serve my purpose
1. Wont work for ?, '' & ' '.  I can first replace ?, '  ' etc with NaN but that brings issues 2, 3
2.  Still have to run some sort of for loop to only ignore features with lots of missing values.  I guess I can try out ```df.apply()``` in case ```df``` optimizes things, but I don't see a way to add the problematic features to a list within dropna other passing a complex function.
3. ```thresh``` in ```dropna``` is an absolute value and not a percentage value.  Hence, I still have to manually compute it using count

Answer (score 1):

If you can replace the values `?`, `''`, and `' '` with `np.nan`, you can easily compute the percentage of missing values by using the `sum` and the length of the DataFrame. You can replace the missing values with an `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2, '', '?', 4], 'c': [' ', np.nan, '', 5]})

def replace(x):
    idx = x.isin(['', ' ', '?'])
    x[idx] = np.nan
    return x

replaced = df.apply(replace, axis=1) % Values are replaced here
```

Now you can compute the percentage of missing values for each column with this:

```
replaced.isna().sum(axis=0) * 100 / len(replaced)

Output:

a     0.0
b    50.0
c    75.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean logic with `isna`, using @Ricardo Erikson setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [2, '', '?', 4], 'c': [' ', np.nan, '', 5]})

(df.isna() | df.isin(['?','',' '])).mean()
```

Output:

```
a    0.00
b    0.50
c    0.75
dtype: float64
```

Check for NaN with `isna` and use `|`, OR boolean operator, and the use `isin`, plus you can use `mean` to find the percentage missing.