# Python vs Javascript performance comparison

Tags: javascript, python

I did a small experiment of running a fibonacci function both in python and javascript. The time taken has a huge difference.

**Python**

```
import time

def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    fib(40)
    time_taken = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Time taken = {time_taken}s")
```

[image]

**Javascript**

```js
function fib(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}


console.time('fibonacci');
fib(40);
console.timeEnd('fibonacci');
```

[image]

I am trying to understand the reason for such a huge difference in performance. Is it because of the GIL? If yes please add an explanation.

Comment: yes i does feel like it takes about half a minute

Comment: For me, it takes 66101ms in the browser with JS, and 1710ms in Node.js.

Comment: I ran it in a node environment. It took about 1s

Comment: Weird; running the code a second time produces a time of around 3s in the browser as well.

Comment: My this be due to the JIT compilation?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046514/is-there-something-wrong-with-this-python-code-why-does-it-run-so-slow-compared