# Functional programming with Ruby

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

Ruby has support for functional programming features like code blocks and higher-level functions (see Array#map, inject, & select).

How can I write functional code in Ruby?

Would appreciate examples like implementing a callback.

Comment: Ruby is not a functional language.

Comment: Look over this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159797/is-ruby-a-functional-language

Comment: Follow this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833372/functional-code-examples-in-ruby

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, maybe it is not pure functional, but supports some paradigms of  functional programming.

Comment: Thanks @Bijendra. That thread is very informative.

Comment: @khanmizan: what paradigms are those?

Comment: An example like "how to implement callback" isn't much good for this question, because callbacks aren't really the way you do things in pure functional programming. A function called asynchronously can't rely return anything, and do can't do anything useful without side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **yield**

```
def method(foo,bar)
    operation=foo+bar
    yield operation
end
```

then you call it like this:

```
foo=1
bar=2
method(foo,bar) {|result| puts "the result of the operation using arguments #{foo} and #{bar} is #{result}"}
```

the code in the block (a block is basically "a chunk of code" paraphrasing ruby programmers) gets executed in the "yield operation" line, you pass the method a block of code to be executed inside the method defined. This makes Ruby pretty versatile language.

In this case yield receives an argument called "operation". I wrote it that way because you asked for a way to implement a callback.

but you could just wrote

```
def method()
  puts "I'm inside the method"
  yield
end

method(){puts "I'm inside a block"}
```

and it would output

```
I'm inside the method   
I'm inside a block
```